# ORDER BY specific value then rotate through the rest

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users;
```

Where I get back

```
 id    name  ...
 1     ...
 2     ...
 3     ...
 4     ...
```

Now, what I want is to order the result I get back based on the id, and rotate the order based on that.
For example, lets say I want to sort based on the ID=3. What I want back is:

```
 id    name  ...
 3     ...
 4     ...
 1     ...
 2     ...
```

Is this possible directly in MySQL, or do I have to do this server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simply:

```
SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id<3,id
```

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it be: `id < 3, id`? Order within all records with id less than three, and rest would be unpredictable.

Comment: @samuil yes... it's that I wrote :-)

Comment: Works like a charm. Only -- I'm not sure if it is possible to convince mysql to use index with this order. `explain` shows `index, filesort` for this query.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried all the answers and this one seems to be the simplest solution.In terms of performance, all of the answers are performing equally well, atleast in phpmyadmin profiler. Though I dont have much experience profiling stuff.

Comment: @dadord: As far as I can tell, this query can have problems with big sets of data, because of lack of indexing. Keep in mind, that if your dataset will grow too much, it might be worth reviewing.

Comment: @samuil Thanks for the heads up. It shouldn't be a problem in my case because I do include a WHERE in there that significantly reduces the results to a maximum of 20 or so :-)

Comment: @samuil the question is only for order. I think is useless to optimize too soon, maybe the original query is more complex. Good point however, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN id < 3 THEN id + (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) 
    ELSE id 
END
```

but note, that mysql won't be able to use index for that ordering. I think that making this rotation outside of SQL server is most pragmatic solution.

Comment: If users were deleted, `count(*)` is not larger than the largest `id`.  Sorting on `max(id)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort on two columns, the first only being filled when `id >= 3`:

```
order by
    case 
    when id >= 3 then -id
    end desc
,   id
```

The first column is sorted on `-id` so we can sort descending, where `null` is at the end.

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a616bc/2/0)

Comment: Does sorting by `-id desc` allow SQL to use index?